# Using the "With Clause" SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Can someone show me a sample SQL server script that I can look at that uses the **"With Clause"**?

I am trying to use this clause to iterate through 200 databases that contain the same table that I am trying to run a query on.  I am trying to avoid using a cursor because the query time takes too long as well as using a while a loop.

Can someone advise me as to what I can do.

Thank you.

Comment: `WITH` won't help you on this task. Are all the databases on the same instance? What is the code you are running on all of them?

Comment: Martin, yes, they are on the same instance.  each database has the same table.  I want to use the sum function to gather all the data from the tables and have the name of each database populate in a temporary table with the following columns: DBNAME, IMG_COUNT, DATE.  The name of the table is tbldoc or dbo.tbldoc.  Each database contains this table and all have the same columns that I wish to query. What would with do to speed this up, rather than using a cursor or while loop?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just a poke, but here's another way to write FizzBuzz :)
100 rows is enough to show the WITH statement, I reckon.

```
;WITH t100 AS (
 SELECT n=number
 FROM master..spt_values
 WHERE type='P' and number between 1 and 100
)                
 SELECT
    ISNULL(NULLIF(
    CASE WHEN n % 3 = 0 THEN 'Fizz' Else '' END +
    CASE WHEN n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz' Else '' END, ''), RIGHT(n,3))
 FROM t100
```

But the real power behind WITH (known as Common Table Expression http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx "CTE") in SQL Server 2005 and above is the Recursion, as below where the table is built up through iterations adding to the virtual-table each time.

```
;WITH t100 AS (
 SELECT n=1
 union all
 SELECT n+1
 FROM t100
 WHERE n < 100
)                
 SELECT
    ISNULL(NULLIF(
    CASE WHEN n % 3 = 0 THEN 'Fizz' Else '' END +
    CASE WHEN n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz' Else '' END, ''), RIGHT(n,3))
 FROM t100
```

To run a similar query in all database, you can use the undocumented **sp_msforeachdb**. It has been mentioned in another answer, but it is sp_msforeachdb, not sp_foreachdb.

Be careful when using it though, as some things are not what you expect. Consider this example

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'select count(*) from sys.objects'
```

Instead of the counts of objects within each DB, you will get the SAME count reported, begin that of the current DB.
To get around this, always "use" the database first. Note the square brackets to qualify multi-word database names.

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use [?]; select count(*) from sys.objects'
```

For your specific query about populating a tally table, you can use something like the below. Not sure about the DATE column, so this tally table has only the DBNAME and IMG_COUNT columns, but hope it helps you.

```
create table #tbl (dbname sysname, img_count int);

exec sp_msforeachdb '
use [?];
if object_id(''tbldoc'') is not null
insert #tbl
select ''?'', count(*) from tbldoc'

select * from #tbl
```

Comment: ok, it seems like the best way for me to do this is to use a while loop which is supposedly faster in processing compared to a while loop.  this is what i have so far

Comment: This really helped me a lot to achieve the getting data on paging button click of grid. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

There are two types of **WITH** clauses:

Here is the FizzBuzz in SQL form, using a WITH common table expression (CTE).

```
;WITH mil AS (
 SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.column_id ) [n]
 FROM master.sys.all_columns as c
 CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns as c2
)                
 SELECT CASE WHEN n  % 3 = 0 THEN
             CASE WHEN n  % 5 = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz' ELSE 'Fizz' END
        WHEN n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz'
        ELSE CAST(n AS char(6))
     END + CHAR(13)
 FROM mil
```

Here is a select statement also using a WITH clause

```
SELECT * FROM orders WITH (NOLOCK) where order_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the sp_foreachdb procedure.

Comment: That does just use a cursor so probably won't be a dramatic speed performance on the OP's current system (not that I suspect that this is going to be possible)

Comment: Martin, yes, they are on the same instance.  each database has the same table.  I want to use the sum function on a specific column to gather all the data from the tables and have the name of each database populate in a temporary table with the following columns: DBNAME, IMG_COUNT, DATE.  The name of the table is tbldoc or dbo.tbldoc.  Each database contains this table and all have the same columns that I wish to query. What would with do to speed this up, rather than using a cursor or while loop?

Comment: There isn't any way of doing this without looping. However the bulk of the time will be taken up on the individual queries not the loop itself. You could (1) Try and parallelise it a bit. (2) Make sure that `tbldoc` in all databases has appropriate indexes for the query tou are running or (3) Try and introduce some precalculation.