# Can the result of this 'from' be reused?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw this the following sql in my friend's .sql scripts:

```
from (
 .....
) a

select col1,col2 from a
select col3 from a where ...
```

My friend said the sql in the `'from'` will be excuted only once and its result will be reused when `'a'` is called.

I just want to confirm is this true? If so, how could RMDB store its result and when would the result be released?

Comment: This is not standard SQL.  Perhaps this is available as unusual syntax in some databases, but none come to mind immediately for me.

Comment: Does the first select have ....Into A....?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff say this is not standars SQL

Comment: This is not sql ansi as @GordonLinoff pointed, it can be done in SQL-Server, and it's most common used with `WITH` keyword. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696041/using-the-with-clause-sql-server-2008

Comment: It might be valid Hibernate SQL, but I'm not sure if multiple selects are allowed.

Comment: @RicardoPontual . . . "this" *cannot* be done in SQL Server.  A CTE in SQL Server differs from the code in the question in two important ways:  (1) It can only be used in a single `select`; (2) the CTE operates like a (non-materialized) view so the code is executed multiple times.